# i am a beginner in python trying to use playsound module ,when run program ,it shows The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI

Tags: playsound

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\masai\Documents\programming languages\sound.py", line 4, in 
playsound('//C://Users//masai//Downloads//03. Arambh (online-audio-converter.com)')
File "C:\Users\masai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
File "C:\Users\masai\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 31, in winCommand
raise PlaysoundException(exceptionMessage)
playsound.PlaysoundException:
Error 263 for command:
open "//C://Users//masai//Downloads//03. Arambh (online-audio-converter.com)" alias playsound_0.4501127239858208
The specified device is not open or is not recognized by MCI.

Comment: Hi there, usually when posting questions a code example should be provided to reproduce the issue. You can use three opening back tick characters to create code blocks, and close the code block with another three back ticks. ` <-- these

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.